# How to spindown(sleep) a SATA hard disk drive under Windows?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, sleep, esata

I am using a 3.5" SATA HDD from the eSATA port of my laptop. The HDD is powered with another ATX power supply. Each time I unplug the eSATA, I cannot make the HDD spindown before I power off the ATX.

So, any tool to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried savely removing it (perhaps only for USB) or unmounting the drive?

Else [have a look at HotSwap!](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm)

You can treat the eSata like a HDD you're trying to hot swap, thus turning it off. But instead of swapping it, you just leave it off.

Features:

- Compatible user interface with the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon on Windows XP.
- Confirms all volumes assigned to the drive are not in use before removing it.
- Spin-down the drive to remove the drive safely.
- Not only fixed disk drives but also other type of drives can be removed.
- Runs without user interface by given command line switch and also the message popup can be suppressed.

[image]

Comment: I do try to unmount(using the icon of removeable devides) the device before unplug, but I cannot be sure whether microsoft will spindown the HDD.

I'd like a tiny tool to help me to make sure it do spindown.

Comment: :-) "savely removing" is a great phrase!

Answer (score 1):

Hard Disk Sentinel at www.HDSentinel.com is a good tool that lets you adjust your Advanced Power Management of each individual hard drive.  It allows a range of settings that effect the spindown (or not).  It also lets you adjust the AAM (Advanced Acoustic Management) - how loud the hard drive sounds vs the tradeoff of increased seek performance.

The free version has a nag screen but lets you adjust all these indefinitely.

Answer (score -1):

hdparm will not work with all SATA controllers, (for example, I have Promise FastTrak TX2300 and hdparm issues an error message).

I think there are other utilities that may work, for example sdparm and sg3_utils, both have a Windows port. I will try them.